# Vitamio crash on LibChecker. Added Vitamio using gradle

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, vitamio

I add viatmio library using gradle in android studio V2.2 . 
It crash at

```
if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
```

with exception like

```
couldn't find "libvinit.so"


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Need any suggestions or correction. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version of Vitamio from [Official Web site](https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/) and Add this line to initiate
`Vitamio.isInitialized(this);`